# How to make my app more shiny?

Tags: iphone, user-interface

im writing a litte iPhone App and are now searching for some styling Guides to make my App a little more shiny :)

For example add rounded rectangles to group Informations. 
Style my cells, e.g. add a little border to my images I display in the cells.

Is there a guide / tutorial i can read? 
What can be done with Interface Builder?

I found several guides for rounded rectangles, but what is the best way? Some recommend to do it with a button? Ohters with an ImageView and graphics?

Thanks for your links / hints!

Comment: FWIW, I don't think this question should be closed as Not Programming Related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at:
http://www.techjini.com/blog/2009/07/09/tools-for-iphone-ui-user-interface-design-mockups-wireframes-or-just-a-sketch/

It is a list of UI tools for iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html